# Variable reverting to initialised value

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, printing, response

In the following I've taken out irrelevant code. I've created a field called `printString`. The `calculateButton_Click` method does a heap of stuff, then I want to send it to a print-friendly page using `response.write`. However the `printString` variable doesn't seem to ever stop being "DEFAULT". DEFAULT is all that shows up on my blank page when I click the `printButton_Click`. Trimmed code below:

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string _printString = "DEFAULT";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Buffer = true;
        }

        protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _printString = "";

_printString = "HARRY POTTER™: THE EXHIBITION Invoice<BR>Today's date: " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "<BR>Visit date: " +
            dateSelectedString + "<BR><BR><BR>Adult tickets: " + numAdult + "<BR>Child tickets: " + numChild + "<BR>Family Passes: " + numFamily +
            "<BR>Payment method: " + paymentType + "<BR>Total to pay: $" + totalPrice.ToString("0.00");

    }

    protected void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write(_printString);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printButton is clicked it is using the value `DEFAULT` from when the variable is being set.

```
private string _printString = "DEFAULT";
```

Is your problem.  You need to maintain the state of `printString` when the variable is modified. Simply assigning `_printString` to another value is not persisting the change.  You could either write a function to assign `_printString` to the correct value when `printButton` is clicked, use `ViewState` or `Session` or assign _printString in the `printButton` click function directly as shown below.

```
protected void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _printString = "Harry Potter";

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(_printString);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Will result in `Harry Potter` being wrote to the page.

To use `Session`:

```
protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       _printString = "HARRY POTTER™: THE EXHIBITION Invoice<BR>Today's date: " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "<BR>Visit date: " +
        dateSelectedString + "<BR><BR><BR>Adult tickets: " + numAdult + "<BR>Child tickets: " + numChild + "<BR>Family Passes: " + numFamily +
        "<BR>Payment method: " + paymentType + "<BR>Total to pay: $" + totalPrice.ToString("0.00");

       Session["PrintString"] = _printString;
}

protected void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _printString = (string)Session["PrintString"];

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(_printString);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

**ViewState:**

```
ViewState["PrintString"] = "HarryPotter";
```

Then to retrieve the value you can simply do:

```
 _printString = (string)ViewState["PrintString"];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: How do I pass through the giant string from the calculate method? In Java we do this by using the fields.

Comment: The `ViewState` would also be very appropriate to store such data between button clicks.

Comment: @nunespascal - yeah - I have included that in my post.

Answer (score 2):

All (instance) variables are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle since HTTP is stateless(even the controls).  You could use a `ViewState`, `HiddenField` or `Session` variable instead.

```
private string PrintString 
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["PrintString "] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty((String)ViewState["PrintString"]))
        {
            ViewState["PrintString"] = "DEFAULT";
        }
        return ViewState["PrintString"].ToString();
    }
    set { ViewState["PrintString"] = value; }
}
```

There are other options:

[**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The button click event is causing a postback and the `_printString` value is not being persisted. You need to store it in the calculate method via [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) or [Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms972976.aspx) and then set it in the print for example: -

```
 protected void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     _printString = "";
     _printString = "HARRY POTTER™: THE EXHIBITION Invoice<BR>Today's date: " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "<BR>Visit date: " +
        dateSelectedString + "<BR><BR><BR>Adult tickets: " + numAdult + "<BR>Child tickets: " + numChild + "<BR>Family Passes: " + numFamily +
        "<BR>Payment method: " + paymentType + "<BR>Total to pay: $" + totalPrice.ToString("0.00");
     Session["bigstring"] = _printString;
 }

 protected void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Clear();
     _printString = Session["bigstring"].ToString();
     Response.Write(_printString);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
 }
```